# How to bundle UI with Microservice

Tags: angular, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, angular-universal

We have nearly 70+ **microservices with Spring Cloud**. Everything works as expected. But, we have a big giant UI Angular app which is consuming all services.

I have read somewhere that the better approach is to bundle UI along with service to avoid dependencies. Sounds good, but couldn't pointers for it. Just got that there is a **UI composition pattern** but couldn't connect how could it really help.b

How do we really **couple a service with the UI** as one system and ship(deploy) it? **Is it really worth**? If so, can someone point me to any sample example? How to **combine different HTML responses** of various services at client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [Self-Contained Systems (SCS)](http://scs-architecture.org/index.html) is what you are looking for. Each Service provides its own UI which may be part of the whole.

A brute force (and not that beautiful) integration approach would be separate Angular Apps presented in iframes.
Sadly I have too little experience on that topic to help you more.